# Count sem retornar 0 no Presto

Tags: sql

Minha query é essa:

```
with dates as (
  SELECT CAST(date_column AS DATE) DAY 
    FROM (
      VALUES (
        SEQUENCE(cast('2019-10-29' AS date), current_date, INTERVAL '1' DAY)
      )
    ) AS t1(date_array)
   CROSS JOIN UNNEST(date_array) AS t2(date_column)
)

SELECT p.profile_id, coalesce(ct,0) AS ct, DAY 
  FROM connect_profiles p
  left JOIN (
    SELECT profile_id, COUNT(distinct visit_id) as ct, dates.DAY 
      FROM connect_visits v 
      right join dates on dates.DAY = cast(v.visit_created_at as date)
      where 
        web_site_id in ('10','11') and
        metadata like '%logged%'
      GROUP BY profile_id, dates.DAY
  ) CountQuery ON p.profile_id = CountQuery.profile_id
  where p.profile_id = 733194
  order by DAY asc
```

Eu já tentei tudo que eu achei na internet que pudesse me ajudar a retornar o `0` no `count()` quando não tem nenhuma visita atrelada ao `profile_id` num dia específico, mas nunca pega. Não sei o que eu estou fazendo errado. Ele só mostra os dias que o `profile_id` fez visita, mas eu quero que ele me mostre todos os dias que estão no intervalo de tempo determinado na consulta, independente se teve consulta ou não.

Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

O resultado que eu recebo é esse aqui:

```
 profile_id ct  DAY
1   733194  4   2019-11-04
2   733194  9   2019-11-06
3   733194  6   2019-11-07
4   733194  3   2019-11-09
5   733194  101 2019-11-10
6   733194  38  2019-11-11
7   733194  16  2019-11-12
8   733194  6   2019-11-14
9   733194  3   2019-11-17
10  733194  5   2019-11-18
11  733194  5   2019-11-19
12  733194  3   2019-11-20
13  733194  6   2019-11-21
14  733194  3   2019-11-22
15  733194  1   2019-11-23
16  733194  4   2019-11-24
17  733194  7   2019-11-25
18  733194  5   2019-11-26
19  733194  3   2019-11-27
20  733194  4   2019-11-28
21  733194  4   2019-11-30
22  733194  4   2019-12-01
23  733194  6   2019-12-02
24  733194  6   2019-12-03
25  733194  7   2019-12-05
26  733194  1   2019-12-06
27  733194  4   2019-12-07
28  733194  2   2019-12-08
29  733194  8   2019-12-09
30  733194  5   2019-12-10
31  733194  6   2019-12-11
32  733194  2   2019-12-12
33  733194  1   2019-12-13
34  733194  2   2019-12-14
35  733194  2   2019-12-15
36  733194  2   2019-12-16
```

Eu quero o count desde 29/10/2019. Quero que apareça o 0 se não tiver visita em algum dia.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar nvl/coalesce?

Comment: tentei aqui em cima: SELECT p.profile_id, coalesce(ct,0) AS ct, DAY

Answer (score 0):

O problema com as funções de agregação (`COUNT`, `SUM`, `AVG`, etc) é que elas não computam valores nulos.

Quando temos valores `NULL` na própria coluna ou por causa de um `LEFT JOIN` ou `RIGHT JOIN` por exemplo, o banco não sabe como computar esse valores. Como o banco pode responder as perguntas por exemplo:

- quanto vale um null se estiver contando?
- quanto vale um null numa soma?

Precisamos instruir ao banco como tratar isso na query. Para isso, o valor dentro do `COUNT` por exemplo não pode ser um null, então você pode usar a função `coalesce` que já tem no seu código  **dentro do count**, por exemplo assim:  `COUNT(coalesce(visit_id, 0))`.

Como zero é um valor, ele será contado. Seria o mesmo resultado de somar se o valor fosse 1, assim: `SUM(coalesce(visit_id, 1))`, ou seja, está convertendo e "dizendo" para a função como tratar os nulos.

Lembre-se que nesse caso, cada registro será processando pelo `coalesce` para verificar se é necessário substituir o nulo. Se sua tabela for muito grande, isso pode gerar um problema de performance. Nesse caso, talvez seja necessário "dizer" para o `count` contar os nulos separador, algo mais ou menos assim:

`SELECT COUNT(visit_id) FROM connect_visits WHERE visit_id IS NULL`, tendo de fazer duas queries, ou uma sub-query, apenas para ilustrar o exemplo e dar outras opções.

Montem aqui no [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6fa2/8) um exemplo com valores nulos e como ficam os resultados usando esses exemplos acima.

Comment: Eu não consigo usar o coalesce com o distinct na consulta de dentro. Dá erro. E quando eu faço só o coalesce dentro e coloco o count na consulta de cima me mostra o mesmo resultado de antes, não muda nada :(

 
SELECT count(distinct ct) AS ct, p.profile_id, DAY
FROM connect_profiles p
left JOIN
(SELECT profile_id, coalesce(visit_id,0) as ct, dates.DAY
 FROM connect_visits v right join dates on dates.DAY = cast(v.visit_created_at as date)
 where web_site_id in ('10','11') 
 and metadata like '%logged%' 
 ) CountQuery